# how to get text of option knowing just its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, html-select

Let's say i have such code:

```
<select id="select" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="A1">abc</option>
 <option value="A2">cde</option>
 <option value="A3">efg</option>
</select>
```

And an array:

```
var selected = ["A1", "A3"];
```

I want to iterate through `selected` array to get second array containing text of option markups with appropriate values. Values are unique:

```
var texts = [ "abc", "efg" ];
```

How to achieve that in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `:selected` selector to find selected options and map() to create array

```
var texts = $('#select option:selected').map(function(){
  return $(this).text()
}).get();
```

Or use attribute selector while iterating the `selected` array

```
var $opts = $('#select option')
var texts = selected.map(function(val){
  return $opts.filter('[value="' + val + '"]').text()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get elements using value attribute and generate the array using [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) method. Where use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to generate a single selector to avoid iteration over the array.

```js
var selected = ["A1", "A3"];

var res = $('[value="' + selected.join('"],[value="') + '"]').map(function() {
  return this.text; // or $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="A1">abc</option>
  <option value="A2">cde</option>
  <option value="A3">efg</option>
</select>
```

---

If you are trying to get selected elements text then use [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) pseudo-class selector.

```js
var res = $('select option:selected').map(function() {
  return this.text; // or $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="A1" selected>abc</option>
  <option value="A2">cde</option>
  <option value="A3" selected>efg</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `this.value` is already what `selected` element is, OP wants text

Comment: Read question about what objective is

Comment: @charlietfl : [`text - Contains the text content of the element.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)

Comment: ok..didn't know that about `<option>`..learn something new all the time!

Comment: @charlietfl :  even I'd learned last week from one of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute "value" selector for option:

```
    var selected = ["A1", "A3"];
    var text= [];
    for(var i=0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        text.push($('#select option[value=' + selected[i] + ']').text());
    }
```

Comment: I do not have access to selector. I have values: options that holds list of all options in particular select markup and select that holds the select

Comment: Yes, you can use those values as shown above to retrieve the option texts